# Create ID for each object in a ListObjectClass

Tags: java, arrays

I have two classes, my object class, and the `ListObjectClass`.
In my constructor of `ListObjectClass` I create an array of an object looking like this:

```
private ObjectClass[] name;
```

And I have to make an `ID` for each `ObjectClass`, but I don't know how can I do that, do I need to make a `getID()` and `setID()` on `ObjectClass`?

Constructor of `ListObject` Class:

```
private int id;
private float pes;
private int nRegistres;
private RellotgeObjecte[] rellotge;

public LlistaRegistreEsportiu(int n) {

    this.nRegistres = 0;
    rellotge = new RellotgeObjecte[n];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the ID as an argument of the constructor:

```
public LlistaRegistreEsportiu(int n, int id) {
    this.nRegistres = 0;
    rellotge = new RellotgeObjecte[n];
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: I mean it doesnt compile, bc its not the entire class, only the principal part